# How to set auto reload in angular project on cloud9?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I am using Angular CLI on Cloud9, i am facing an issue that my angular project is not auto reloading. Need some help.

Comment: this happens when you save?

Comment: Yes, when I save the reload doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: can you try this: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --live-reload-port 8081

Comment: Patricio it is giving error as "Invalid Host header"